# Sequences of real numbers, arithmetic mean.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Given a sequence of real numbers, a move consists of choosing two terms and replacing each with their arithmetic mean. Show that there exists a sequence of 2015 distinct real numbers such that after one initial move is applied to the sequence — no matter what move — there is always a way to continue with a finite sequence of moves so as to obtain in the end a constant sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_{1007}$ be distinct positive real numbers. Set $a_{-i}=-a_i$ for i=1,...,1007, and let $a_0 = 0$. Then the sequence $(a_{-1007}, a_{-1006}, ..., a_{-1}, a_0, a_1, ..., a_{1006}, a_{1007})$ can be reduced to the constant sequence $(0,0,...,0)$ in $1007$ moves, where in each move we operate on a different pair $(a_{-i}, a_i) = (-a_i, a_i)$, which the move sends to $(0,0)$. (Note that this sequence has $2015$ distinct elements.)

Suppose we make an initial move which takes $(a_i, a_j)$ to $(\frac{a_i + a_j}{2}, \frac{a_i + a_j}{2})$ for $-1007 \le i < j \le 1007$. If both $i$ and $j$ are nonzero, we can make a second move which takes $(a_{-i}, a_{-j}) = (-a_i, -a_j)$ to $(\frac{-a_i - a_j}{2},\frac{-a_i - a_j}{2})$. Then we can make 2 additional moves which take $(\frac{-a_i - a_j}{2}, \frac{a_i + a_j}{2})$ to $(0,0)$. Then for all $k \not\in \{0,i,j,-i,-j\}$ we can map $(a_k, a_{-k})$ to $(0,0)$. Thus we get to a constant sequence in $4+1005=1009$ moves.

Suppose $i=0$. Then $(0, a_j)$ goes to $(\frac{a_j}{2}, \frac{a_j}{2})$. Choose $k \not\in \{0,j\}$ and map $(a_k, a_{-k}) = (a_k, -a_k)$ to $(0,0)$. Taking one of the $0$'s, map $(0, a_{-j}) = (0, -a_j)$ to $(\frac{-a_j}{2}, \frac{-a_j}{2})$. Then make two additional moves which map $(\frac{a_j}{2}, \frac{-a_j}{2})$ to $(0,0)$. For all $h \not\in \{0,j,-j,k,-k\}$ we can map $(a_h, a_{-h})$ to $(0,0)$. Thus we get to a constant sequence in $5+1005=1010$ moves. (We can follow exactly the same procedure if $j=0$, exchanging $i$ and $j$).

This shows that many starting sequences have the specified property. For example, we could take $a_i = i$ to get $(-1007,-1006,...,0,1,...,1007)$. Also, any translation of a sequence that satisfies the property will also have the property. If $(a_{-1007}, ..., a_{1007})$ satisfies the property, then so does $(a_{-1007} + \bar{a}, ..., a_{1007} + \bar{a})$, for any real number $\bar{a}$ (replacing $0$ by $\bar{a}$ in the argument above).

Answer (score 1):

We try induction. It is clearly true for {$x_1$}.
 Assume it is true for the sequence {$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$,.....$x_n$} and show it is true for {$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$,.....$x_n$, ${x_{n+1}}$} ={$x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$,.....$x_n$}∪{${x_{n+1}}$}.We can by hypothesis make constant the first sequence and the result follows immediately, in particular for n = 2015.

**Additional question**.-What are the functions satisfying the same property? Is it just the arithmetic mean of two terms?